# Search bar wont return results

Tags: php, html, mysql, ajax

Cant figure out what's going wrong here, no errors are appearing but nothing is being returned. The search bar should return the names of other users from my database.

Here is Test.php:

```
<?php
    session_start();
?>  

<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function search(partialSearch){
            $.ajax({
                url:"PHP.php",
                type:"POST",
                data {partialSearch:partialSearch},
                success:function(result){
                    $("#results").html(result);
                }
            });
        };
    </script>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="container">

        <h3>Find Other users</h3>

        <input type="text" name="partialSearch"onkeyup="search(this.value)"/>
        <div id="results"></div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is PHP.php

```
<?php

    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "root";
    $dbname = "coursework_db";

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 

    $partialSearch = $_POST['partialSearch'];

    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT username FROM members WHERE username LIKE ? ");
    $stmt->bind_param('s',$partialSearch);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($username);
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
        $searchResults[] = $username;
        echo "<div>".$searchResults."</div>";
    }
?>
```

Here is the SQL table:

```
CREATE TABLE members (
memberID int(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
username VARCHAR(65) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
password VARCHAR(65) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (memberID)
);
```

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: Have you tried checking the console log for errors?

Comment: “no errors are appearing” because you don't check for errors. You have errors both in js and in php. In JS you have at least a  brackets issue. In php your result is `<div>Array</div><div>Array</div>...`

Comment: Well, I got this working. You should be able to piece this all together.

Comment: how? i have made the changes but still not right

Comment: @ConnorRoberts Consult my answer below. *Enjoy*

Comment: @ConnorRoberts You're most welcome Connor, *cheers*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides the missing colon in

```
data {partialSearch:partialSearch},
    ^
```

which should read as:

```
data: {partialSearch:partialSearch},
```

Your PHP/MySQL syntax is off.

You're declaring `$row` in

```
while ($row = $stmt->fetch())
```

but not using it anywhere.

However, that's kind of a bad for a good as you don't need that much code to start with.

Plus, since you're using LIKE, you're not using the right syntax for it.

See the manual on this: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-comparison-functions.html

What your code should look like is this:

```
$partialSearch = "%". $_POST['partialSearch'] ."%";
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT username FROM members WHERE username LIKE ? ");

$stmt->bind_param('s',$partialSearch);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($username);

while ($stmt->fetch()) {

    echo $username;

    echo "<div>".$searchResults."</div>";
}
```

Having checked your console and for errors, you'd of seen what was going on or not.

The JS console would have thrown you:

> SyntaxError: missing : after property id

If that still doesn't work for you, then you most likely have errors in your database somewhere.

Consult:

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Answer (score 0):

you seem tyo be using  $username  twice-

first for the database access

```
 $username = "root";
```

and then to reference the database results

```
$stmt->bind_result($username);
```

which would seem to cause a conflict since $username="root"  - try changing the name to a different variable and see if that makes a difference; eg:

```
$stmt->bind_result($user_name);
```

also you have not declared  $searchResults to be an array before pushing elements into it, add the following before the while loop:

```
$searchResults = array();
```

Comment: Thank you, did not pick up on that. Have made these changes but still does not provide the results?

Answer (score 0):

Concatenate `$partialSearch` with `%` wildcards.

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT username FROM members WHERE username LIKE ? ");
 $partialSearch = "%". $_POST['partialSearch'] ."%";
$stmt->bind_param('s',$partialSearch);
 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

you are also missing a ":" in the Ajax query - should be:

```
data: {partialSearch:partialSearch},
```